# packing slip without prices

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.2, packing-slip

How to edit the packing slip to not show prices?

The invoice print-out shows the prices so I am not sure why the packing slip needs to.

**If you want to enclose one that is a gift for someone, it should not show the price.**

Comment: What Prices are you referring to ? I don't think default Magento packaging slip has product prices.